# Data getter inside Model or ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, mvvm

I'm working on an app I created for myself using the MVVM architecture. On my `ViewModel` I have a `list_items` that, when changed, updates the corresponding UI element on the `View`. The list of items depends on the state of other UI elements. Right now I have this method on the `Model`:

```
get_list_items(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Where `arg1, arg2, arg3` comes from the `ViewModel`, which contains the state of the UI.

I know that business logic should be placed on the `Model`, that's why I'm inclined to place this method on the `Model`. So my questions are:

1. Should I place this method on the `ViewModel`?
2. Should my `Model` have methods that promote data access to other objects?

Answer (score 1):

*I study hobby wise and am by no means an expert or highly experienced.*

Ad 2: No, your model should not contain methods which promote access to other objects. You'll neglect the entire concept of "separation of concerns".

Ad 1: No. This method depends on a possible state of a view. You see where this is going. Now one is asking the model to do view-related stuff.

Either use the ViewModel, or observe whether perhaps a "service" class is needed for complex business logic stuff. In this case the View sends data to the service, the service requests data from the model and then sends the results to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should choose based on the nature of the data

If the list of items is static or rarely changes, you can put it in the Model and access it from the View Model whenever you need it. This way, you avoid unnecessary updates and keep your Model simple and consistent.

If the list of items is dynamic and depends on user input or other external factors, you can put it in the View Model and use data binding or observers to update the View accordingly.

If the list of items is complex and requires some processing or validation before displaying it, you can put it in a separate class or service that handles the logic and provides the data to the View Model. It'll be easier to test and with this flexibility.